# How to get all non empty nodes from XElement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to get all nodes from an XElement that actually has a value,
currently I'm using this code:

```
var nodes = from node in elem.Nodes()
            where node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                  ((XElement) node).Value.Length >  0
            select node;
```

Is there a build in operator to do this operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything like this built in. Are you sure you want to include elements that have subelements though? For example:

```
XElement e = new XElement("Foo", new XElement("Bar"));
Console.WriteLine(e);
Console.WriteLine(e.Value.Length);
```

This will print:

```
<Foo>
  <Bar />
</Foo>
0
```

... so `Foo` would be included as an "empty" node even though it contains another element. Is that definitely what you're after?

Comment: No I don't, I only want the non empty leaf nodes of the passed element.

Will this do the job?

var e = from node in elem.Elements()
        where !node.HasElements && node.Value.Length > 0
        select node;

Comment: @Arjor: You might also want to think about attributes... you might want to test for !element.DescendantNodes().Any()